# Proof that this diagram commutes

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, induction, lie-groups

This is an exercise in a book I'm reading:

Define an $\mathbb R$-linear isomorphism $f_n : \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb R^{2n}$ by 
$$(x_1 + iy_1, x_2 + iy_2, \dots) \mapsto (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, \dots )$$

Let $A \in M^n (\mathbb C)$ and define $R_A(v) = v \cdot A$. Furthermore define an injective homomorphism $\rho_n : M^n(\mathbb C) \to M^{2n}(\mathbb R)$ as $A_{ij}\mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cc} a_{ij} & b_{ij} \\ -b_{ij} & a_{ij} \end{array}\right)$ if $A_{ij}=(a_{ij} + i b_{ij})$. Show that the following diagram commutes:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \mathbb C^n @>\displaystyle f_n>> \mathbb R^{2n}\\
    @V \displaystyle R_A V V\# @VV \displaystyle{R_{\rho_n(A)}} V\\
    \mathbb C^n @>>\displaystyle f_n> \mathbb R^{2n}
    \end{CD}

So I thought maybe induction could yield a short proof: can you tell me if this is correct:

It is easy to show that this is true if $n=1$. We assume that it is true for $n\le N$ and we consider the case $n=N+1$. Let $A$ be an $N+1$-square matrix. We divide it into $4$ blocks of sizes $2\times 2$ and $N-1 \times N-1$. By induction hypothesis when restricted to each block the diagram commutes. Hence the diagram commutes for $n=N+1$.

Comment: Your induction doesn't look right: two of your blocks are of sizes $(N-1) \times 2$ and $2 \times (N-1)$, which aren't of the form to be covered by your inductive hypothesis. Also, why are you using the hypothesis for $(N-1)$ rather than that for $N$? You're effectively doing two separate inductions for odd and even $n$, and would need to consider a second base case $n=2$.

Comment: You might want to look into the idea of extension of scalars, which covers similar issues in a more general setting.

Comment: @HTFB Are you saying induction is not possible or just that my proof contains mistakes?

Comment: It's certainly possible. I'm not sure it adds much value as a method over a direct proof.

Comment: @HTFB I was hoping than it would be shorter than the direct proof (in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HTFB says, your induction seems wrong. You might be able to get away with an induction in which on an $N \times N$ matrix, you take four overlapping $(N-1) \times (N-1)$ submatrices, each anchored in one corner.

But an alternative is to just write things out. I'll do half of it.

Fix $n > 0$. Suppose that $k$ is an integer between 0 and $n-1$ (I'm going to use 0-based indexing, so the upper left corner of a matrix is $m_{00}$, to make things easier). I'm also going to write $f$ instead of $f_n$. Let suppose that the entries of the vector $v$ are

$$
v_i = x_i + \mathbf i y_i
$$

Then we have 
$$
R_A(v)_k = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} v_i A_{ik}.
$$
And
$$
f(v)_{2k} = Re(v_k) = x_k \\
f(v)_{2k+1} = Im(v_k) =  y_k.
$$
And finally,
\begin{align}
{\rho(A)}_{2k, 2s} &= a_{ks} \\
{\rho(A)}_{2k+1, 2s} &= -b_{ks} \\
{\rho(A)}_{2k, 2s+1} &= b_{ks} \\
{\rho(A)}_{2k+1, 2s+1} &= a_{ks}.
\end{align}

And then 
\begin{align}
f(R_A(v))_{2k} &= Re(R_A(v)_k) \\
&= Re(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} v_i A_{ik})\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} Re(v_i A_{ik})\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left( Re(v_i) Re( A_{ik}) - Im(v_i) Im( A_{ik}) \right)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left( x_i a_{ik} - y_i b_{ik} \right)\\
\end{align}

Now we just need to find $R_{\rho(A)}(f(v))$ and compare it to this. Well,
\begin{align}
R_{\rho(A)}(f(v))_{2k} &= (f(v) \cdot \rho(A))_{2k} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{2n-1} f(v)_j \rho(A)_{j,2k}.
\end{align}
I'm going to split this last sum into a sum with even indices and an sum with odd indices:
\begin{align}
R_{\rho(A)}(f(v))_{2k} 
&= \sum_{j=0}^{2n-1} f(v)_j \rho(A)_{j,2k}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} f(v)_{2i} \rho(A)_{2i,2k} + \sum_{i=0}^{n} f(v)_{2i+1} \rho(A)_{2i+1,2k}.
\end{align}

Applying the formulas for elements of $f(v)$ from above, this becomes
\begin{align}
R_{\rho(A)}(f(v))_{2k} 
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} x_i \rho(A)_{2i,2k} + \sum_{i=0}^{n} y_i \rho(A)_{2i+1,2k}
\end{align}
And now we can apply the formulas for the entries of $\rho(A)$ to get
\begin{align}
R_{\rho(A)}(f(v))_{2k} 
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} x_i \rho(A)_{2i,2k} + \sum_{i=0}^{n} y_i \rho(A)_{2i+1,2k}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} x_i a_{ik} + \sum_{i=0}^{n} y_i (-b_{ik}) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (x_i a_{ik} - y_i b_{ik}).
\end{align}
And now we just notice that those two things are equal.

Then we repeat the whole exercise for the $2k+1$ entry of the vector in the lower right, and we're done. I'm not going to write that out, and indeed, I'm not sure why I wrote *this* out, except that if you get rid of the summation limits, and compress a few steps into one, this really becomes pretty straightforward. Indeed, this is the sort of thing that probably shouldn't be given an explicit proof except in, say, an introductory linear algebra text where you're first talking about complex vector spaces; in any paper to be read by professional mathematicians, it's really not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Is there no shorter way to prove this? " Indeed, this is the sort of thing that probably shouldn't be given an explicit proof " -- I agree. But it's an exercise in a book I'm reading. The idea with induction was mine, but now I'm hoping to find something shorter and more insightful.

Comment: Do you think you can make a short proof if you assume that we have shown that the diagram for the map $g_n : \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb R^{2n}$ defined by $$(x_1 + iy_1, x_2 + iy_2, \dots) \mapsto (x_1, x_2, \dots ,y_1, y_2, \dots )$$ commutes? I proved that and now I thought maybe using that could give a shorter proof...

Comment: For the map $g_n$ I have the homo $\rho_n (A) = \rho_n (X + i Y) = \begin{array}{cc} X & Y \\ - Y & X \end{array}$

Comment: If there is really no short proof then I would not have done the exercise at all but my hope is that someone can show me that it's actually possible.

Answer (score 0):

Considering $\mathbb{C}$ as a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, its action on itself by multiplication gives an embedding $\rho:\mathbb{C} \to M_2(\mathbb{R})$; explictly,
$$\rho(x + iy) = \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ -y & x \end{pmatrix}$$
(modulo an irrelevant choice of sign for $y$, at least), as you describe. The map $\rho$ then induces an isomorphism of complex vector spaces $f:\mathbb{C}^n \to M^n$, where $M = \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$-action $z.x = \rho(z)x$. Thus for any $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $\alpha:\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$, the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \mathbb C^n @>\displaystyle f>> M^n\\
    @V \displaystyle \alpha V V @VV \displaystyle\alpha' V\\
    \mathbb C^n @>>\displaystyle f> M^n
    \end{CD}
clearly commutes, where $\alpha'(x) = f \alpha f^{-1}(x)$. Explicitly, for a map $\alpha$ with $i$th component $\alpha(x)_i = g_{ij} x_j$ for some fixed $g\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, the corresponding map $\alpha'$ has $i$th component $$\alpha'(fx)_i = f(g_{ij} x_j)_i = g_{ij}.f(x_j) = \rho(g_{ij}) f(x_j).$$
Unraveling the notation, the commutative diagram above is then just your original diagram.

Comment: You define $\alpha'(x) = f \alpha f^{-1}(x)$ but in the next display style equation you write $\alpha'(fx)_i = f(g_{ij} x_j)_i $. Is this a typo?

Comment: No: $\alpha'(fx) = f\alpha(x) = f(gx)$. (Since $f$ is surjective, we can write an arbitrary element of $M^n$ as $f(x)$ for some $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$.)

Comment: Also, I'm being sloppy in talking about the "$i$th component" of $\alpha'$, but hopefully the meaning is clear from context. I actually mean the $i$th copy of $M$ inside $M^n$, which is nominally a real $2$-vector.